# Copy Float point data to Mat

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I am new to opencv, I am trying to read pixel values from a text file. Which I am reading and storing it in a floating point vector.

```
vector<float> iArray;
```

I want to create a image from that floating point data. I have to copy the float data to the Mat.

I am doing this and it seems not to be working.

```
Mat image(640, 480, CV_32FC3);
for (int i = 0; i < iArray.size(); ++i)
    image = iArray.at(i);
```

Just like other data type I assume that copying the value to image will be adequate but however it is not. I am sure I am wrong. Please help me. THank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you're trying to do something without reading documentation what is wrong way.

Why did you create `Mat` with 3 channels? Does your input image has 3 channels? It seems that you have to do the following:

```
Mat image(Size(640,480) CV_32FC1);
int k=0;
for (int i = 0; i < image.rows; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < image.cols; ++j)
    {
        image.at<float>(i,j) = iArray[k];
        ++k;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I realized my mistake. I took Mat at 1D which is wrong. One more question.